# Replacement for EBS Environment Variables in CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy, aws-parameter-store

I have been using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my .Net based Web API service. I am using the environment variables to push the settings like `SecretKey` `AccessKey` `DBPassword` etc. 
Now, we are moving from EBS to CodeDeploy where we do not have the option to push these settings into the `web.config` file of my application. After exploring a bit, I found that we can make use of Parameter Store in AWS to store the DBPassword and others. However, in order to read from the Parameter Store, we need to have the `SecretKey` and `AccessKey`. So what would be the best to achieve it in CodeDeploy?

Comment: Which framework are you on ? .NET Core ? version also would help.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.6.2

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/ You should not also need AWS Secret Key and Access Key would that help your decision making.